# Outlook Emails ReceivedTime Out of Order in Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

Longtime lurker and first-time poster, so I'll try to be as specific as possible here!

The goal of a script I am writing is to grab a start and end date from an excel file and use that range to pull the most recent email from Outlook that lies within that range. The information within these emails is then used to make a report in a spreadsheet.

The script works as intended EXCEPT for the fact that there are certain dates whose ReceivedTime property is out of order and it winds up grabbing the earliest possible entry instead of the latest.

If I type `$Emails.ReceivedTime` into the console, it will show them out of order which is causing the issue. If I type `$Emails.ReceivedTime | sort`, the issue goes away. My problem is that no matter where I've tried plugging this into my script, it will just hang and never finish execution.

```
Function GetEmails ()
{
    Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    $Inbox = $Namespace.Folders.Item('UsernameHere').Folders.Item('Inbox').Items
    return $Inbox
}

Function GetXYZ($Emails) {

    $XYZ = $null
    foreach($Email in $Emails) {   
        if ($Email.SenderEmailAddress -ne $null -and $Email.SenderEmailAddress.Contains('xyz@123.com')) {  
            if (($Email.ReceivedTime -le $end_date) -and ($Email.ReceivedTime -ge $start_date)) {  

                $XYZ = New-Object psobject -Property @{'Sender' = $Email.SenderEmailAddress; 'Time' = $Email.ReceivedTime; 'Body' = $Email.Body}                  
            }

        }
    }

    #Split the body of the email into an array and remove whitespace from the array.
    $Array = $XYZ.Body.Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    #Create an array of numeric values only
    $numArray = @()
    $numArray += $Array -replace '[^.0-9]'

    $junk1, [int]$Item1, [int]Item2, [int]$Item3, $junk2 = $numArray

    return New-Object psobject -Property @{'Name' = 'XYZ'; 'Time' = $XYZ.Time; 'Item1' = $Item1.toString("N0"); 'Item2' = $Item2.toString("N0"); 'Item3' = $Item3.toString("N0")}
}


$Emails = GetEmails

GetXYZ($Emails)

#Rest of the code runs here to do things unrelated to my problem...
```

**This is the first 10 email ReceivedTimes currently:**

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 7:22:19 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 6:55:07 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 6:22:18 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 6:03:07 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 6:02:21 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 5:22:17 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 4:22:03 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 3:55:07 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 3:22:18 AM*

*Thursday, May 23, 2019 3:01:33 AM*

**This is what the first 10 lines SHOULD be:**

*Wednesday, April 3, 2019 9:00:07 AM*

*Thursday, April 4, 2019 9:00:04 AM*

*Friday, April 5, 2019 9:00:08 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 5:03:22 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 5:11:22 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 5:22:29 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 7:08:59 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 8:11:08 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 8:55:45 AM*

*Saturday, April 6, 2019 9:00:02 AM*

If I left out anything important here please feel free to let me know, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never call `Items.Sort`, you should not expect any particular order. In your particular case, if you want the Items collection to be sorted on the `ReceivedTime` property, you should call `Items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true)`.

Also, as Eugene mentioned, if you are only processing a subset of items, teh filtering must be done on the server side - use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`. IN your particular case, `Items.Restrict` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your input. I must have been using the wrong syntax or missed a " or something because it didn't work when trying to use the sort method before but it does now! As for the filtering, I will be reading over it and implementing it for the next iteration. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: See the following link for the search syntax and examples:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all items in a folder is not really a good idea:

```
 foreach($Email in $Emails)
```

Instead, I'd suggest getting a small subset of items for processing (a bunch). For example, you may extract items for each week or month and etc. I would recommend using the `Find` and `FindNext` methods if you have a small number of Outlook items in the collection (see the Items.Count property). On the other hand, the `Restrict` method works faster than `Find`/`FindNext` methods if there is a large number of items in the collection and only a few items are expected to be found.

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Get unread Outlook e-mail items from the Inbox folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/27/outlook-get-unread-items/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestions! I will definitely be going over your articles so I can apply them to what I have. I assume I'll be relying on the Restrict method as the inbox to parse has ~3000 at any given time and any within the inbox may need to be pulled for one reason or another. Thank you again for the advice!